# if I have several boolean returns with recursive method, which one overcomes?

Tags: java, recursion, boolean

I have a boolean method that needs to check a condition and return true false.

Assuming I do

```
return match(a,pattern,aCounter+1,0);
```

And one time the result was false- would false come out as the final return input, or does it depend on the last boolean value returned?
Thanks!

Comment: what is `match` and where is the recursion? The answer depends on what and how it process the arguments. As it is currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

If one recursive call of `match` returns `false`, that `false` value is returned to the method that called it, which decides what to do with it. If the caller method returns that value to its own caller and so on, that `false` will eventually reach the original caller of your recursive method.